# MySQL - Timestamp(8) alternative?

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, sqldatatypes

I tried creating this table by running this a few years ago using an earlier version of MySQL and it worked fine. It appears as though there is now a problem with timestamp(8) in the more recent versions of MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE top_hits (
  sid int(11),
  ip varchar(20),
  cdate timestamp(8)
)
```

What could I use as an alternative to line 4's timestamp(8)? YYYYMMDD

```
cdate timestamp(8)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `(8)` part in the field definition does **not** have any effect on:

- the size of the column (in bytes)
- the range of values stored in it (1970 to partway 2038)
- whether or not you can store hour, minute and seconds in it

The `(8)` portion specifies the *display size*. When doing a `SELECT`, MySQL will return the first `XYZ` portion of the date from the timestamp [as described here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/timestamp-pre-4-1.html).

So, just eliminate the display portion from your create table query. This will create a `timestamp` column. You can format the timestamp (e.g. chop off the time portion, etc) using MySQL functions or in PHP.

Or use the [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) datatype which does not store the time portion at all.

Answer (score 3):

You need [DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) type, it stores year, month and day.

If you need to format output (YYYYMMDD), use [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

Answer (score 2):

the syntax of

```
timestamp(N)
```

is deprecated as of mysql 5

you may select the date OF YOUR CHOICE

```
SELECT date(ts)+0 from t;
```

DATETIME data type takes 8 byte of storege timestamp takes 4 bytes and date time takes wider range of dates